# How do I stop a fixed element from going beyond the footer with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made the "Get Started" element in the sidebar fixed when it scrolls beyond a certain point but on smaller laptop screens (14" to 18") when the user scrolls down it ends up running into the footer.

I want to set it so that once it detects that the sticky is within, say 10 pixels of the footer, it stops.

Link to site

http://previewyournewwebsite.info/otsl/compare-reverse-mortgage-loan-products

Here's the code I used:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
        var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
        var div_top = $('.sticky-anchor').offset().top;
        if (window_top > div_top)
            $('.sticky-element').addClass('sticky')
        else
            $('.sticky-element').removeClass('sticky');
    }

    $(function() {
        if ($('.sticky-anchor').length != 0){
            $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
            sticky_relocate();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like that

```
function sticky_relocate() {
    var sticky_element = $('.sticky-element');
    var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
    var div_top = $('.sticky-anchor').offset().top;
    var div_height = sticky_element.height();
    var footer_top = $('.footer').offset().top;
    if (window_top > div_top) {
        sticky_element.addClass('sticky')
    } else {
        sticky_element.removeClass('sticky');
    }
    if(div_top + div_height > footer_top - 10) {
        sticky_element.css("top", footer_top - 10);   
    }
}

$(function() {
    if ($('.sticky-anchor').length != 0){
        $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
        sticky_relocate();
    }
});
```

Get the height of the div and check if its top position + height is not more then the top position of the footer.

Comment: doesn't work man. the $('.sticky-anchor').offset().top figure does not change